# Show(e.g. Push) from a viewcontroller to a navigation controller works?! Why?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I am new to IOS programming and I am using the Swift language.
After doing a couple of beginner apps. I have had some trouble on figuring the difference between the **Show(e.g. Push)** and the deprecated **Push** segues.

What I want to do is to Show/Push from a **ViewController A**(embeded with **Navigation Controller B** ) to a **Navigation Controller C** (containing a **View Controller D**).

Since when I disable the *"Use size classes"*, the **Push** segue doesn't work and will report error *"pushing to a navigation controller is not supported"*. This error makes sense since you can only push regular view controllers.

However when I enable the *"Use size classes"* (which turns the Viewcontroller to a square instead of a rectangle), I was able to **Show(e.g. Push)** to a navigation controller, which really confuses me.

So what's the main difference between the **Show(e.g. Push)** and the deprecated **Push**? As to my knowledge there is no major functional difference but the fact seems to prove me wrong and makes me confused..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

I have recreated the behavior you observe.  The **Show (e.g Push)** segue does indeed work from one viewController embedded in a navigationController to a second viewController embedded in a different navigationController.

Note that when the push happens, the second viewController slides in in the normal push way, and a back button appears that takes you back to the first viewController.  This tells you that the second viewController is actually being pushed onto the stack of the first navigationController.  So instead of giving you the error message, it is simply ignoring your second navigationController.

When using a navigationController, only the first viewController is imbedded in a navigationController.  You don't have to embed subsequent viewControllers in a navigationController, because when you wire up the **Push** segue from a previous viewController in the navigationController's stack, the Storyboard will recognize that this new viewController is controlled by a navigationController and it will add the navigationBar at the top.

---

**Original Answer:**

A **Show (e.g. Push)** segue is an *Adaptive Segue*.  It chooses the correct segue type based upon the situation.

- If your source viewController is in embedded in a Navigation Controller, it does a **Push**.
- If your source viewController is in a SplitViewController without a NavigationController, it does a **Replace**.
- In all other cases, it does a **Modal** segue.

So, it works because it is actually doing a **Modal** segue in your case, which works if you aren't using size classes.  You will notice that the presented viewController actually slides in from the bottom which is a tell-tale sign of a **Modal** segue.

You can find information about it here:
[Backward Compatibility of Active Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/BackwardCompatibilityofActiveSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH46-SW1).

Comment: thanks for the answer! According to your answer my case works because it is actually doing a Modal segue? But how come the screen actually shifts from right to cover the top of the source view controller, which looks like a Push segue?

Comment: Basically What I want to do is to Show/Push from a ViewController A(embeded with Navigation Controller B ) to a Navigation Controller C (containing a View Controller D).  And when I use Show, it actually gives me a  Push effect (screen slides from right)

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated answer!! Solved the problem that made me scratch my head for days! I can't upvote this answer due to "reputation" restrction. Thanks!